# FPDF running locally, but not online

Tags: php, fpdf

**UPDATE:** I've tried disabling all references to the font and used Arial instead. It works now, but as mentioned it messes with ÆØÅ which aren't included in this font.
In any case, **this pretty much confirms that the font-path is the issue.**

I'm trying to generate PDF-files with tFPDF.
When I run my code on a local server, it works perfectly, but when I upload it to my webhost, it starts acting up.
The first issue that I encountered was that `ttfonts.php` gave me an error that stated that it could not open a certain font file, which it was for some reason trying to find in my local directory rather than the online one. I have no idea why it would do this, but in an attempt to fix it, I defined the `FPDF_FONTPATH` php constant to multiple different versions of the online servers filepath as instructed by the guide on fpdf's website. All of them resulted in 1 of 2 outcomes:

1. I would get the same error, somehow still with the local file path rather than the defined constant.
2. I would just get a blank page in the php file that contains the code (not a blank pdf).
   The second outcome could imply that the font folder path problem was solved but that a second problem emerged behind it. Or it could just imply that the defined constant was failing to read on the server.

   It is worth noting that the reason I need tFPDF and this particular unifont is that I wanted a font that had the danish letters "æøå" and didn't look extremely pixelated.
   I have no idea where in the process this problem is occurring, and without an error I am lost as to where to look. I tried changing the permissions of the php file to allow it to write, but that didn't help either.
   Maybe I am overlooking some extremely basic issue, maybe I'm not. In either case, here's the php code minus the page "content":

   ```
   <?php
   define('FPDF_FONTPATH','home/USERNAME/public_html/WEBSITENAME/intra/paycheck2/font');
   require('paycheck2/tfpdf.php');
   $pdf = new tFPDF();
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);
   $pdf->AddFont('DejaVuB','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
   $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',9);
   $pdf->Image('images/IMAGENAME1.png',10,10,-130);
   $pdf->Image('images/IMAGENAME2.png',50,11,-100);

   //(Text content code here)

   $pdf->Output();
   ?>
   ```

I included the images just in case the paths of these could have some significance. Other than that its just text using a few php variables here and there.
The filepath in the above example results in a blank page (result 2), other attempted filepaths include:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','public_html/WEBSITENAME/intra/paycheck2/font');
//Blank page result (2)
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/paycheck2/font');
//Blank page result (2)
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','paycheck2/font');
//Can't open file C:\wamp\www\SITENAME\paycheck2/font/unifont/DejaVuSans.ttf
//Result 1; the error code containing my local URL, which is also given when no constant is specified. Likely a sign that the constant was rejected.
```

I tried more variations, but like I said, they all resulted in one of these 2 outcomes. Does anyone have any idea what to do about this?

Comment: "contains the code"? WHich code? PDF? or PHP? if you get the raw pdf code, then you probably have a "headers already sent" situation. if you get php, then the server's misconfigured and/or the php install is broken.

Comment: Is the site on a windows or nix server? Referring to this: `Can't open file C:\wamp\www\SITENAME\...`

Comment: Your path: `home/USERNAME/public_html/...` is a relative path, not absolute. You need to prepend the path with a `/` to make it absolute: `/home/USERNAME/public_html/...` or better yet, if the "paycheck2"-folder is in the same folder as the above script, use: `define('FPDF_FONTPATH', __DIR__ . '/paycheck2/font');` (\_\_DIR\_\_ returns the absolute path of the current file).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The "dir" syntax results in the error with my local directory. Why? Who knows... It is in the same folder by the way, which is why it works on local.

Comment: @MarcB The PHP file that runs the PDF generating code turns up blank in result nr 1. So I'm guessing its either the server or the php install, although I haven't had any other issues with PHP on it thus far. Any suggestions on where to look? It uses C-panel as its UI.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't know if its UNIX or Windows, how do I tell? Thus far I haven't needed to do much besides dumping my code files onto it and dealing with the SQL databases.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The absolute path gave the same error by the way.

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried disabling all references to the font and used Arial instead. It works now, but as mentioned it messes with ÆØÅ which aren't included in this font.
In any case, this pretty much confirms that the font-path is the issue.